# Windows - Executing an executable (.exe) without the .exe extension

Tags: python, windows

I need to be able to execute a .exe file in Python that has been renamed without the file extension (for example, let's say .joe - it doesn't represent anything that I know of).

Let's say I have "HelloWorld.exe", I then rename it to "HelloWorld.joe" and need to execute it.

Looking around, os.system is often used to execute .exe files, but I haven't been able to get it working without the .exe extension.

The file cannot be renamed to have the .exe extension (or for that matter anything), in this "scenario", I do not have access to the source code of the executable.

Comment: Renaming the file will do nothing to prevent someone decompiling it. Despite your claims to the contrary, this feels more like what a malware developer would try to do in the hope that a non-exe would skip security checks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `subprocess.call`? Works for me.
[Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) 
Example:

```
#renamed from MobilePASS.exe, runs the program
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["d:/MobilePASS.ubi"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot imagine a valid reason to break Windows philosophy. Microsoft always said that on its system the file extension determined the type of file and its usage. There are already many cross platfomr programs, for example firefox in named `firefox` on Unix-like systems and `firefox.exe` on Windows system.

EDIT

That being said, Windows accepts what you give it as command, provided it is in a correct executable format. So if you create a program `HelloWorld.exe` and rename it `HelloWorld.joe` :

- cmd.exe will start the program when you type `HelloWorld.joe` at the prompt (tested on Windows XP and Windows 7)
- Python 2.7 and 3.4 should start it either using `os.system` or with the `subprocess` module (confirmed by  eryksun)

<del>You cannot use `os.system` call with a *badly* named file (in Microsoft's sense) because under the hood, `os.system` uses `cmd.exe`. It is a Microsoft program that looks at the file extension to know what to do with it, and will never execute (as an exe) a file that do not have the exe extension.</del>

<del>You will not be able to use the subprocess module with `shell=True` for exactly the same reason. But when `shell=False`, it directly calls `CreateProcess` that accept any name as the name of a valid executable (provided it is ...) as said by zeller.</del>

Comment: @eryksun : I failed to test it because I was sure that windows was more strict on extension ... Thank you for fixing that !